# Can I run a report in Google Analytics that will tell me the email domain of those who use mailto?

Tags: google-analytics

We have several mailto links on our site, is there a way to track/create a report in google analytics that will list the email domain of those who clicked and/or submitted an email?

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="mailto:me@example.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'mailto', 'example.com')">Email me</a>`

Is that what you are looking for?  There is no way to get an external email program to send hits to google analytics.